# SvnAnt not working on open suse 11.4

Tags: svn, ant, build-automation

I want to use SvnAnt to checkout the latest code from our svn repository, build and then deploy it. I have done all the other parts and only the checking out part is left.I am using svnant 1.2.1 . But in svnant.jar , i only found the *.xml file. Here is what I did  for the same :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project name="Update" basedir="." default="update">

  <!--  all properties are in build.properties -->
  <property file="build.properties" />
  <path id="project.classpath">
    <pathelement location="${svnjavahl.jar}" />
    <pathelement location="${svnant.jar}" />
    <pathelement location="${svnClientAdapter.jar}" />
  </path>
  <property name="project.svn.url" value="projectURL" />

  <typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/s​vnantlib.xml" classpathref="project.classpath"/>

  <target name="update">
    <svn>
      <checkout url="${project.svn.url}" revision="HEAD" destPath="." />
    </svn>
  </target>

</project>
```

However, when running it,it gives the following :

```
    crazyabtliv@linux-hknk:~> ant -v -f svn.xml 
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.2 compiled on December 20 2010
Buildfile: /home/crazyabtliv/svn.xml
Detected Java version: 1.6 in: /usr/java/jdk1.6.0_26/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /home/crazyabtliv/svn.xml with URI = file:/home/crazyabtliv/svn.xml
Project base dir set to: /home/crazyabtliv
parsing buildfile jar:file:/home/crazyabtliv/apache-ant-1.8.2/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/home/crazyabtliv/apache-ant-1.8.2/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading /home/crazyabtliv/build.properties
  [typedef] Could not load definitions from resource org/tigris​/subversion/svnant/s​vnantlib.xml. It could not be found.
Build sequence for target(s) `update' is [update]
Complete build sequence is [update, ]

update:

BUILD FAILED
/home/crazyabtliv/svn.xml:16: Problem: failed to create task or type svn
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.

    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.getNotFoundException(UnknownElement.java:487)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:419)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:163)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 0 seconds
crazyabtliv@linux-hknk:~>
```

What is the issue ? Are there any other jar files that have to be added ? Something else to be done ? Thanks 
I also tried keeping the jar files in ant/lib, but, that gave the same error

Comment: which version of svnant are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **svnant 1.1** or higher you need to have the taskdef like this:

```
<typedef resource="org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml" classpathref="project.classpath" />
```

The method:

```
<taskdef resource="svntask.properties" classpathref="project.classpath"/>
```

is for the **svnant 1.0** version.

You can check this easily, by opening the svnant*.jar file and look if there is

- org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml
- svntask.properties

Depending on the result you have to use the first or second approach.

Another alternative is specifying the relevant class:

```
<taskdef name="svn" 
    className="org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask"
    classpathref="project.classpath"/>
```

Comment: I am using svnant 1.2.1 . Let me check :)

Comment: @crazyaboutliv 1.2.1 contains org/tigris/subversion/svnant/svnantlib.xml

Comment: Yes I have updated the code to reflect that. I checked, and changed the code accordingly. it still gives the same error though :(

Comment: @crazyaboutliv can you run ant in verbose mode(ant -v), and check the classpaths, you might not point to the jars correctly.

Comment: I have tried the verbose mode. I am pasting the text in the answer. I also tried keeping the jars in ant/lib and then not specifying the classpath explicitly. Both of them give the same error

Comment: @crazyaboutliv the output you gave is not enough. If you run ant -v -f svn.xml you should get a HUGE amount of output, some of it contains classpaths, that list every jar that is loaded. We need this to look closer at the problem.

Comment: I have infact run it using ant -v -f svn.xml.  Sadly thats all that ant shows :(  It does not seem to be loading anything except ant.jar  . I don't know why , yet

Comment: @crazyaboutliv i've added another alternative, if this throws a classnotfoundexception, something is wrong with your ant :D

Comment: I won't be surprised if that is the case :) I have run into so many issues like this :( Thanks for all the help !

Comment: Would you believe it, still same problem ! ! ! ! I think maybe I am doing something wrong somewhere else with the jar files :( Should I specify the path to the jar files or keep them in ant/lib ?

Comment: @crazyaboutliv it is easier to have them in ANT_HOME/lib, but the other approach has merits, too (depends on your situation). Have you checked, that ANT_HOME is set correctly and points to the directory where you put all the jars? Maybe try to reinstall ant :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9085/discussion-between-crazyaboutliv-and-oers)

Comment: I have set ANT_HOME correctly , confirmed coz it points to ANT_HOME/lib/ant.jar in the -v mode ( posted in the Q) . I tried removing all the explicit classpaths and letting Ant search, that is not working either. Same problem. :(